# model attribute on a second (redirected) JSP page not working, throws error - Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My welcome page is Login.jsp. On submit it redirects to another page which enlists dummy transaction details of the logged in user. 
[please view this image link to see the login flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJpGd.jpg)

However, when i try adding a form in the second page with a model attribute, it throws an error.

### Login.jsp - form bit of code

```
  <form:form method="POST" action="login2.html" modelAttribute="user" id="form">  
<table>
    <tr><td>  <form:input path="user_id" placeholder="User ID:" value="" disabled="true"/></td></tr>    
        <tr><td><form:input path="email_id" placeholder="Email ID:" value="" /></td></tr>
    <tr> <td> <form:password path="password" placeholder="Password" value="" /> </td></tr>
     </table> 
 <input type="submit" value="Log-in"/> 
  </form:form>
```

### Controller class action for login2.html

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView login( @ModelAttribute("user") UserBean u1, BindingResult result) {
        /*some  code to call service class*/
        /* lst is a list<Users>*/
        model.put("t1", lst);
        return new ModelAndView("save", model);
    }
```

### Save.jsp (redirected page)

```
<form:form method="POST" action="saveTransaction.html" modelAttribute="trans" id="form">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="transaction_id">Transaction ID:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="transaction_id" value="${i.transaction_id}" readonly="true"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="user_id">User ID:</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="user_id" value="${i.user_id}"/></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
              </tr> 
            </table>            
        </form:form>




 <c:if test="${!empty t1}">
<table align="left" border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>transaction ID</th>
            <th>User ID</th>

            </tr>

            <c:forEach var="i" items="${t1}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${i.transaction_id}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${i.user_id}"/></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="edit.html?id=${i.transaction_id}">Edit</a> | <a href="delete.html?id=${i.transaction_id}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
    </c:if>
```

Controller class for action - saveTransaction.html

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveTransaction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveTransaction( @ModelAttribute("trans") TransactionBeans t1, BindingResult result) {
    /* some code */
    /* lst is a list<TransactionDetails>*/
    model.put("t1", lst);
    return new ModelAndView("save", model);
        }
```

### TransactionBeans.java - bean class

```
public class TransactionBeans implements Serializable{

    int user_id, transaction_id;


    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }

    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }


    public int getTransaction_id() {
        return transaction_id;
    }

    public void setTransaction_id(int transaction_id) {
        this.transaction_id = transaction_id;
    }   
}
```

This code works with the form - it enlists all the data as i have shown in above screenshot. However, it throws an error with form modelAttribute. Please note, model attributes in both forms are different, binding different tables.
Error thrown:

```
root cause
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'trans' available as request attribute
        org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.save_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(save_jsp.java:208)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.save_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(save_jsp.java:153)
        org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.save_jsp._jspService(save_jsp.java:93)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
```

So does this mean a redirected page cannot have a different model from the calling page binding another set of data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anywhere in your controllers the attributes "user" and "trans" passed into your models. Your views with modelAttribute seem to expect them and it is why you receive this error.

Also it would be great to see your GET method handlers as you only provide the ones associated with POST methods.

I'm maybe missing the point of what you are trying to achieve, but each view renders the model attributes you give to it.

Does-it help if I suggest the following for the controllers ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView login(ModelMap model) {
    model.put("user", new UserBean(0, "", ""));
    return new ModelAndView("Login", model);
 }

@RequestMapping(value = "/login2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView loginPost( @ModelAttribute("user") UserBean u1, ModelMap model, BindingResult result) {
    List<TransactionBeans> lst = service.getAll();
    model.put("t1", lst);

    //Display default transaction
    model.put("trans", new TransactionBeans(0, 0));
    return new ModelAndView("save", model);
}

 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveTransaction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveTransaction(TransactionBeans t1, ModelMap model,BindingResult result) {
        service.save(t1);
        List<TransactionBeans> lst = service.getAll();

        model.put("t1", lst);
        model.put("trans", t1);
        return new ModelAndView("save", model);
  }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(@RequestParam("id") String transactionId, ModelMap model) {
        TransactionBeans trans = service.get(transactionId);
        List<TransactionBeans> lst = service.getAll();

        model.put("t1", lst);
        model.put("trans", trans);
        return new ModelAndView("save", model);
  }
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for replying. Like you said, i had already bound the data from JSP page in corresponding controller methods 'public ModelAndView login( @ModelAttribute("user")" and 'public ModelAndView saveTransaction( @ModelAttribute("trans"). 1st level model mapping worked (login2), but the 2nd page model does not work. If i remove form from 2nd (redirected) save.jsp, i get the complete form enlisting dummy transaction data in a jsp table (screen shot is embedded in the original ost in the link statement "please view this image link to see the login flow".

Comment: But using the same method if i try to bind 2nd page (redirected) save.jsp data, it throws the error. If the binding ethod was wrong it should have not worked at 1st level login page, but it works there. I had done what you suggested except that i do not have a get handler method for security reasons. Thanks.

Comment: You must be missing a @ModelAttribute("user") somewhere in the flow otherwise the 1st page wouldn't work either.

Comment: Have a look to: http://krams915.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-using-modelattribute-in.html, see how they create the getAllAddresses method which makes a global binding. I believe you should have a similar method for your logged-in user

Comment: 1st page works, 2nd page does not and in second page, i dont need user data at all, i need only transaction data from the list in the 2nd page displaying transaction id....    i have sent a message. thanks,, im still trying, will be going through the blog to.. thanks a ton.